# Mako: render with predefined/default items in Context?

Tags: python, templates, mako, defaults

I'm looking for an idiom for setting some common item definitions so that any time I call `render()` on a mako template, those items will be added to the parameters available in the template without having to include them in the parameters to `render()` each time.

The example at http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html suggests that the place I should be looking is in some way of either setting some master `Context` definitions or something, or perhaps a way of merging two contexts:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.runtime import Context
from StringIO import StringIO

mytemplate = Template("hello, ${name}!")
buf = StringIO()
ctx = Context(buf, name="jack")
mytemplate.render_context(ctx)
print(buf.getvalue())
```

I can't find anything explicitly showing an example of doing this, and poking around in `dir(Context)` isn't making anything come to mind. Is this a simple thing to do and I'm just overlooking the obvious? Or is there a standard idiom for this?

Thanks in advance!

Update: I suppose one approach is to explicitly append **kwargs to each call to render(), and that's not bad, as it's explicit:

```
template = self.template_lookup.get_template("index.mako.html")
return template.render(var1=val1, var2=val2, **common_vars)
```

Still curious if there's a way to "fully predefine" such items.